PhpStorm Using Remote Preview
I am evaluating PhpStorm and have successfully added my PHP interpreter as a remote connection to my local dev server IP. It detects the version and appears normal. However, when I click the preview icon in a .php file it takes me to Bad Gateway and suggests adding a local PHP interpreter. Without my server configured, the same happens. (502 Bad Gateway is displayed)
Am I missing something or is remote server (note, the files are local) not an option? I have tried to use the Remote Development beta feature but it wants me to pay £80+ and I'm on a trial. Is this legit the only way? I want to preview from the remote dev server with my local files.
I expect to have PhpStorm open the remote server IP address in a browser, display the output of a simple hello world file using the PHP interpreter I configured.

From what I'm getting from your description -- you need to set up a Deployment entry and mark it as Default for this project. Then the IDE will use that URL for Preview / Open in browser kind of actions. Because by default it uses built-in simple web server that uses local PHP to handle the PHP requests.

Yes, that made sense. Can you post an answer cause help is showing a option to add SFTP but that's not what I want.

You can try using the "In place" type of entry -- in your case it's URL that matters the most.

So go Tools -> Deployment?

Yes. Check the help pages: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tutorial-deployment-in-product.html 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-browsers.html 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-built-in-web-server.html#built-in-preview P.S. The actual "Preview" functionality should use local server (I'm not using it, so cannot say for 100% though but it logical to be this way)

So I’d ideally like a specific url to be opened based on the file. I’d configure the url on a per-file basis. If it’s possible I could load url from xml file. Is this possible?

"Is this possible?" Not for "Open in browser" and alike. As it uses a simple "base url" + current file path. You can use Run/Debug Configuration for that, "PHP Web Page" kind, as the most appropriate in this context -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/run-debug-configuration-php-web-application.html Once created, when you have that Configuration selected, clicking "Run" will open your browser with that URL.

OK, that works for me. Thank you.
